# SQL Server : try to find max value of counted row

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have table like this

```
| Country | Age  |
+---------+------+
| SWEDEN  |  43  |
| SWEDEN  |  17  |
| SWEDEN  |  43  |  
| SWEDEN  |  43  |
| SWEDEN  |  17  |
| GERMANY |  17  |
| GERMANY |  17  |
| GERMANY |  17  |
| GERMANY |  44  |
| GERMANY |  44  |
| SWEDEN  |  43  |
| SWEDEN  |  17  |
| GERMANY |  13  |
| SWEDEN  |  17  |
| SWEDEN  |  43  |
```

And I can count ages in the country like this

```
| Country  | Age  | CountOfAge |
+----------+------+------------+
| GERMANY  |  13  |     1      |
| GERMANY  |  17  |     3      |
| SWEDEN   |  17  |     4      |
| SWEDEN   |  43  |     5      |
| GERMANY  |  44  |     2      |
```

I want max age in country like this

```
| Country  | Age  | CountOfAge |
+----------+------+------------+
| GERMANY  |  17  |    3       |
| SWEDEN   |  43  |    5       |
```

I tried with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT  
    X.country, X.age, X.countOfAge
FROM 
    (SELECT country, age, COUNT(age) AS countOfAge
     FROM MOCK
     GROUP BY country, age) X
```

I count the age but I can't filter the max of counted age

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: You could use a GROUPBY statement and the MAX aggregate function. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either [RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql) or [DENSE_RANK()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql) would provide the same results in this case, but read their documentation to understand the difference in behavior between the two - especially the gaps in numbers returned by RANK().

```sql
SELECT
    country,
    age,
    countOfAge
FROM (
    SELECT
        country,
        age,
        COUNT(age) AS countOfAge,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY COUNT(age) DESC) AS ranking
    FROM MOCK
    GROUP BY country, age
) X
WHERE ranking = 1;
```